# How to avoid a double shape when extruding with the mirror modifier

Tags: mirror

I'm following this tutorial from Andrew Price to create an Anvil and when I extrude a face it creates two shapes instead of one. I don't know where the problem comes from and how to solve it. See a screenshot here:

[image]

On his video when he extract it, it creates only one shape:

[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and how to solve it. Thanks alot!

Comment: tick mark the clipping option in the Mirror modifier

Comment: In Mirror option, there is clipping check box, just try to tick, it will make it single by joining them together..

Comment: The problem is caused by the face at the symmetry plane. It closes the shape in the original model and is copied to the other side, creating two closed shapes.

Answer (score 2):

In your Mirror modifier, make sure the clipping option is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>B</kbd> when you inset the face that you are now extruding, so that the ends which are matching the other mirrored side are joined together at the middle. You might have missed the part where Andrew explained this problem in his tutorial at 07:12. He explains it quite well so sure you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. The fix I found is that you can increase Merge Limit in your mirror modifier option for a bigger merge.